# How can I improve academic English?

Tags: writing

I'm a PhD student in Mathematics. I love learning and studying mathematical things. Everytime I read interesting article about my PhD topic. Usually I write academic papers to send an indexed journal. But, I got so many regretful responses from the reviewers about writing mistakes. In this context, How can I write fluent academic paper? Is there any web site to help me about this topic?

Sorry my bad english. 
Sincerely.

Comment: I think you just need to read articles online and may read other academic papers. Your English is alright but you just need more practice.

Comment: I'm reading lots of articles but I'm still insufficient. I think that either I study with a good english writer or get help from someone who is writing native. Is there any actual web site where I find friends to correct my entries?

Comment: You may want to have a look at academia.stackexchange

Comment: Where are you at universtiy?

Comment: In Turkey @Araucaria

Comment: @drxy Are there any English-speaking students who need to submit work in Turkish at your university?

Comment: I wish I had a friend as you say. There are many foreign students here but there are few native English speakers. So rest of them are similar to me.

Comment: @drxy If they need help with their Turkish submissions, you could offer to proofread for  them if they proofread for you too. They don't need to be perfect at English - they just need to be better than you! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria, I want to express my gratitude. Be sure that I'm looking for somebody. If I catch him or her I will send my paper :) Up until now, I haven't found anybody .

Answer (score 3):

All professional academics get other people to read their papers for typos and silly mistakes before submitting them. I wouldn't even *think* about sending an academic paper to a journal, or submitting work at university before getting a friend or colleague of mine to proof-read it for typos such as spelling errors or grammatical slips. This is part of what doing work in academia involves. Get someone to read your paper before you submit it. Learn from their corrections. (Good luck!)